# CollapsingToolbarLayout fade out animation speed

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Is there any way to edit animation speed for CollapsingToolabrLayout ? I mean the fade out animation of View thats collapsed on scroll down.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do it with (in ms):

> app:scrimAnimationDuration="600"

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_size"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:scrimAnimationDuration="600"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                ...

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Also see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setScrimAnimationDuration(long)

Comment: Is there any way to disable it completely, and let me change it however I wish?

Comment: To disable the animation you have to remove the `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"`

Comment: app:scrimAnimationDuration="0” in collapsing toolbar which is completely remove fade out animation